# Unknown GPU show at neofetch

Tags: 20.04, graphics, gpu, i3-wm

Output of `neofetch` is below.

`CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4600H with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 3.000GHz`

`GPU: AMD ATI 04:00.0 Renoir`

My GPU should be `Radeon Graphics`, it says "with" at CPU line, does it mean they are integrated now?

Comment: This is a question you should ask to neofetch developers.

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -short -class display`? Please, [edit] your question and add this information into your original question text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of `neofetch` are correct. AMD Ryzen 5 4600H is a mobile processor for laptops based on the Renoir architecture with integrated Radeon graphics. Renoir is an SoC for the mobile segment and mainstream desktop and workstation based on the Zen 2 microarchitecture incorporating a Vega GPU.